# How to ignore dir when uploading project to codesandbox?

Tags: codesandbox

1.there is no command for codesandbox to upload:

```
$ codesandbox -h
Usage: codesandbox [options] [command]

Options:
  -V, --version    output the version number
  -h, --help       output usage information

Commands:
  deploy|* <path>  deploy an application to CodeSandbox (default)
  login [options]  sign in to your CodeSandbox account or create a new one
  token            get your login token to CodeSandbox
  logout           sign out from CodeSandbox
```

2.and there is no ignore file for codesandbox.

so, it there any way for ignore files/directories when upload codesandbox?